# Blender 2.79 How to Pin Down a Bone to a certain location?

Tags: bones

I try to make a walking animation.
The difficulty is the foot tweening often makes the foot not to stay put. Even though in the keyframe 1 and 2  the bone is in the same location.

Is there a way to pin the bone?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: hello, please show some screenshots

Comment: sometimes you just need to create additional keyframes, you can use the 3D cursor to always make the bone stick to the same location with a shift S > Selected to 3D cursor

Comment: also make sure your interpolation is linear

Answer (score 1):

Your best shot is using IK.

- Give IK to the bone you'd like to stay fixed (make the chain as long as you
  need).
- Create a new bone close to the fixed one to become your
  "ground". This new bone MUST be a child of some bone **higher** in rank than the leg. If you have to, create a new "master" bone to be the parent of all bones.
- Go back to the fixed bone's IK assign the new "ground" bone as the
  target.

[image]

When you move the parent of the leg bones, the feet stay stuck to the ground.

[image]

Only when the feet need to move should you keyframe the "ground bones".

Comment: My rig is IK-ed. 
It can stay the way your image shows. 
But, the problem is when animating.
The moved bone is the result of tweening.
I can't control how blender calculate the motion. From keyframe 1 to 2.

Comment: @JuanFeju Have you tried what moonboots said? For basic animation bezier interpolation is fine, but when IK is involved, all the bones in the chain should be set to linear. See here: https://imgur.com/zp7YINa

If that doesn't solve it and you're sure you don't have some unwanted keyframe hidden somewhere driving things crazy, then you could have a bug. Maybe upload the .blend file?

Comment: So... yes, it seems I have to play with the interpolation, to get things right.

Comment: Yeah, special situations require special interpolations. It's a bummer, but to make our rigs easy to use in the long run, we have to set up a whole lot of tiny things first.